# How to receive full message of unknown length with socket_recv()?

Tags: sockets, bitcoin

I've just started working with sockets.

I've connected to a socket (a bitcoin node), and when I send data with `socket_send()`, the socket will reply with data, *but I don't know what the length of that data will be*.

I would like to receive the full data response with `socket_recv()` and move on to issuing the next `socket_send()`, but I don't know what to put for the `len` or `flags` in this function to get the full message (and not wait for anything more).

**How do you get a full message of unknown length with `socket_recv()`?**

---

> ***ASIDE***: This combination seems to work, but it was just trial and error and I
>   don't know why:
>
> ```
> socket_recv($socket, $buf, 10000000, MSG_WAITALL&MSG_DONTWAIT)
> ```

Comment: Generally speaking a binary network protocol will tell you the length of the message in the first *N* bytes. Read those first, then read the rest of the message. Note: this is not necessarily performant, but it'll get you started.

Comment: @RogerLipscombe Thanks Roger. So I'm assuming that means putting socket_recv in a while loop, storing each byte in to a buffer, and checking that buffer until I find the message length?

Comment: You always need a loop, as `recv()` can return fewer bytes than requested. Even if you know the exact number of bytes in the total message, you have to loop the recv until you have received that many bytes. Network protocols have defined structures. Don't guess, know the details of the protocol you are working with, and then code accordingly.

Comment: If you read the [bitcoin protocol spec](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Protocol_documentation), it tells you exactly how messages are laid out. In particular, see the [Message structure](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Protocol_documentation#Message_structure). Each message has a fixed header, which includes a field that specifies the length of the variable-length data following the header.